# Elasticsearch not returning any hits in Java search API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm stuck with elasticsearch search API. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? Can't make search API working

I use test classes from elasticsearch 1.0.1

1.Get the client

```
Client testClient = ElasticsearchIntegrationTest.client();
```

2.Insert some data

```
client.prepareIndex("elastic_index", "elastic_type", "1")
        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                .field("ID", "1")
                .field("value", "big")
                .endObject())
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

3.Get inserted data (this works)

```
GetResponse response = client.prepareGet("elastic_index", "elastic_type",  "1")
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

4.Search for inserted data (this doesn't work).

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("elastic_index")
        .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
        .setQuery(matchQuery("value", "big"))
        .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
        .setTypes("elastic_type")
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

I've tried all sorts of QueryBuilders with no luck. Number of hits returned is always zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it, I had to refresh the indices for search to work

```
client.admin()
  .indices()
  .prepareRefresh()
  .execute()
  .actionGet();
```

Comment: When running from inside an integration test (`ESIntegTestCase`), `this.refresh()` does the same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all .setFrom() is used to declare an offset, for exemple setFrom(10) will skip the first 10 documents return. Your setFrom is useless.
I do not know whats is doing .setExplain does but maybe you should try a more simple request like following :

```
    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("elastic_index")
            .setTypes("elastic_type")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
            .setQuery(matchQuery("value", "big")).execute().actionGet();
```

Then could you give use your mapping ?  Are you sure your documents is well stored in ElasticSearch ( use elasticsearch-head if you do not)